# Symfony 2 routing with multiple hosts

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm having a strange problem about the symfony 2 routing with multiple host.

The problem : in some case, when we call host1.com/mypath, it does not match any route, because the host does not match.

Example :

I try this route : http://**sub1**.domain.com/mypath.
In the profiler in the routing part, I can see :

> get_mypath    /mypath Path almost matches, but Host "**sub2**.domain.com"
>   does not match the requirement ("**sub1**.domain.com")

However, still in the profiler, I can see that the host is **sub1**.domain.com (in the Request Headers). Strange !

Here is my routing configuration (some of my routing are using sub domains, some other are using different domains):

```
restIp:
    type : rest
    resource: "@xxxBundle/Controller/MyController.php"
    prefix : /
    host: api.{domain}.com
    requirements:
        domain: "(domain1|domain2)"
```

Any idea of the problem ?

Comment: Too bad.. I am in front of the exactly same issue.

Have you find out what's wrong for you ?..